# Windows Server 2008 R2 System process eats RAM

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, memory-usage

We have a Win Server 2008 R2 Standard (ServicePack 1) running, and the machine is equipped with 40 GB RAM

No idea what happened, but the System process is always allocating about 24 GB RAM. That wasn't always the case and I do not know what was / is the reason for it. To restart the system doesn't help, and using different tools to find what is the reason for it failed so far. Using RamMap and the SystemMonitor I can only tell that it is the Private Bytes where the memory is allocated.

Can someone tell me on how to set the memory free again?

Comment: Is this a physical server, or a virtual machine?

Comment: It's physical, and it's only sporting a File Service role

Comment: post pictures (insert links other users with enough reputation can add them) of RAMMap: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx

Comment: Here some screenshots of ProcessExplorer and RamMap

http://i12.photobucket.com/albums/a241/thob_dk/ProcessExplorer_zpspgmmopbp.png

http://i12.photobucket.com/albums/a241/thob_dk/RamMap_zpsbjghz6oc.png

Comment: Is it a print server/have printer drivers installed? I've seen this with SNMP enabled in printer drivers. Seriously...

Comment: Nope, can't see anything else than the file services: http://i12.photobucket.com/albums/a241/thob_dk/Roles_zpslbtwmcsd.png

Comment: can you repro this? How long does it take until kernel allocates memory again? If it is several minutes, you can use xperf. folow this: http://pastebin.com/gR0eGqrX and share the compressed ETL file.

Comment: have you captured the xperf trace or is the issue fixed?

Answer (score -1):

The issue is fixed. In the end it was a RAM-drive that I was missing.